# How do I ignore whitespace between tokens in c++ regex (free spacing mode)

Tags: c++, regex

I am building large regex queries and don't want the regex to fail on a whitespace mismatch. An example applicable to my application would be that I want a regex expression that matches both of the following:

`"int a;"`
`"int  a;"`

I can match both of these using `int\s+a;`, but who wants to read through 100 lines of that!

So I did a quick search and discovered `free spacing mode` (http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) which seems to make `int a;` match both of the above. Great! How do I use it in C++ using the standard's `regex` library?

Boost is also acceptable, but an std solution would be preferred.

Comment: Reg Ex will no matter what remain pretty damn hard to read.

Comment: `free spacing mode` causes spaces *within the regex* to be ignored. It does not do anything for the actual string you are trying to match.

Comment: why not just [SPACE]*?

Comment: @DTSCode because I'll have to insert it instead of every whitespace, and it gets ugly. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Another option is that you could do one pass where you convert all multiple space sequences into a single space, and *then* you can just do `int a;` every time.

Comment: @merlin2011 That might be the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The std regex library is based on the POSIX regular expression grammar. According to your link, that is one that doesn't support free spacing mode.

"Of the flavors discussed in this tutorial, only XML Schema and the POSIX and GNU flavors don't support it"

I believe you should use \s+. If you are generating static expressions, my advice would be to use boost::xpressive.

Bear in mind that reading a complex regex is a skill that takes a lot of practice. If you think \s+ is a problem... just you wait.

Answer (score 1):

1. `free spacing mode` causes spaces within the regex to be ignored. It does not do anything for the actual string you are trying to match.
2. One option for reducing verbosity of your white space regular expressions is that you could do one pass where you convert all multiple space sequences into a single space, and then you can just do `int a;` every time.