# How do I use regex_replace?

Tags: c++, regex

After [asking this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989768/how-do-i-ignore-whitespace-between-tokens-in-c-regex-free-spacing-mode), I realised that I needed to replace all matches within a string with another string. In my case, I want to replace all occurrences of a whitespace with `\s*' (ie. any number of whitespaces will match).

So I devised the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  const std::string someString = "here is some text";
  const std::string output = std::regex_replace(someString.c_str(), std::regex("\\s+"), "\\s*");
}
```

This fails with the following output:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_replace(const char*, std::regex, const char [4])

Working example: http://ideone.com/yEpgXy

Not to be discouraged, I headed over to cplusplus.com and found that my attempt actually matches the first prototype of the `regex_replace` function quite well, so I was surprised the compiler couldn't run it (for your reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_replace/)

So I thought I'd just [run the example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_replace/) they provided for the function:

```
// regex_replace example
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("there is a subsequence in the string\n");
  std::regex e ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");   // matches words beginning by "sub"

  // using string/c-string (3) version:
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"sub-$2");

  // using range/c-string (6) version:
  std::string result;
  std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), s.begin(), s.end(), e, "$2");
  std::cout << result;

  // with flags:
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$1 and $2",std::regex_constants::format_no_copy);
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

But when I run this I get the exact same error!

Working example: http://ideone.com/yEpgXy

So either *ideone.com* or *cplusplus.com* are wrong. Rather than bang my head against the wall trying to diagnose the errors of those far wiser than me I'm going to spare my sanity and ask.

Comment: std::regex is not working properly on GCC until the 4.9 version. Your exemple (ideone) is on gcc 4.8

Comment: Note: cppreference is actually http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace

Comment: @Cubbi My bad. Thanks for picking that up :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to update your compiler to GCC 4.9.

Try using [boosts regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) as an alternative

[regex_replace](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simple code C++ regex_replace only alphanumeric characters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const std::regex pattern("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_]");
    std::string String = "!#!e-ma.il@boomer.zx";
    // std::regex_constants::icase
    // Only first
    // std::string newtext = std::regex_replace( String, pattern, "X", std::regex_constants::format_first_only );
    // All case insensitive
    std::string newtext = std::regex_replace( String, pattern, "", std::regex_constants::icase);
    std::cout << newtext << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Run https://ideone.com/CoMq3r